# What's wrong with my shellcode?

Tags: linux, shellcode

Sorry about this must have been asked and explained thousand times but I don't get it why this code gives me a segmentation fault.
Compiled with nasm for elf 64 and liked with ld.

```
BITS 64          ;
xor  rax, rax    ;
mov  rax, 0x3b   ; LinuxX64 exevce
push 0x68732f2f  ;
push 0x6e690b2f  ;
pop rbx          ; Argv[0] /bin//sh
xor rcx, rcx     ;
push rcx         ;
push rbx         ; 
pop rcx          ; Argv[1] /bin//sh0
xor rsi, rsi     ; just need any GP register 
push rsi         ;
pop rdx          ; Argv[2] 0
syscall          ;
```

Comment: Maybe some reference to memory which is invalid/inaccessible? Anyway, just out of curiosity, how is this related to information security?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and tracing which instruction exactly gives the segfault?

Comment: I've used gdb and right before the system call, my arguments (in rbx rcx) are situated in an unaccessible memory adress.
How am I supposed to deal with this ? I'll try using lea command

Answer (score 0):

Many things were wrong actually, first in 64bits, arguments are passed as **rdi, rsi, rdx ,rcx,** if more we have to use the stack.

```
BITS 64                       ;
xor  rax, rax                 ;
mov  al, 0x3b                 ; EXECVE -> al other wise we get null bytes
xor  rcx, rcx                 ; 
push rcx                      ; PUSH A NULL BYTE
mov  rdi, 0x68732f2f6e69622f  ; /*  
push rdi                      ;     use the stack to fill rdi '"/bin//sh"0'
mov  rdi, rsp                 ; */
xor sil, sil                  ; Argv[2] -> sil otherwise we ge null bytes
syscall                       ;
```